# Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath] Error when querying Firestore - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get some information from a document in firebase. I have done it multiple times but this time I am getting a weird error

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath]
'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart':
package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/…/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 72 pos 7: 'field is String || field is FieldPath'
```

The relevant error-causing widget was

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>
```

Comment: hi, your question is not clear to give an answer!, maybe u can provide a gist stating the exact problem so that we might help you out

Comment: Add your code where you query the Firebase, I think your `where()` clause is wrong.

Comment: You're passing an invalid parameter as the first argument to `where`. To tell you more, we'll need to see the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as the single line you shared isn't enough for that.